How do I stop the 'Turn On Reactions' popup from appearing every time?
I'm on macOS 15.2 and every time I open Zoom or Google Meet the 'Turn on Reactions' pop up appears.
Text
"Turn on Reactions Google Chrome has turned off Reaction Effect. Click on camera icon and select Reactions to add more impact to your gestures"
I don't want to turn this on. Ever. How do I stop this pop up?


Can you try opening QuickTime, starting a video recording, then go to the camera icon in the menu bar and turn off reactions?

I'm seeing the same behavior on any app using the camera and the little "X" is weird, it doesn't dismiss it until you tab to something else. Sorry Apple, I don't want any reactions ever.

I have been looking all over for a solution, thought it was just a Zoom thing but it's a macOS feature with no off switch I can find.  If you have a Mac with Apple silicon with macOS Sonoma or later, you get subjected to this annoying behavior.
https://support.apple.com/en-us/105117
